# Mysql storing and retrieving time and day

Tags: mysql, database, time

I am trying to store a variety of information in MySql like **subject, days of subject, start time, end time and teacher**. I will then retrieve the data and present them in a table where the columns are the **days** and rows are the **time intervals**. How would I then start and what are the things I need to consider?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try. MySql has types to define date() you can subtract them in proper format.

Comment: I have created a table with the `starttime` and `endtime` having `time` data types. The rest are of `varchar` data types.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display data in this way i suggest to store days and time interval of the day in two separate tables :

```
CREATE TABLE day(id int, day date);

CREATE TABLE interval (int id, int day_id, start_time time, end_time time);
```

Then you can query with a simple JOIN :

```
SELECT start_time, end_time FROM interval i
JOIN day d ON d.id = i.day_id
```

If you need the aggregate, reverse the JOIN and use the [SUBTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime) function to calculate the daily interval :

```
SELECT SUBTIME(i.start_date,i.end_date) FROM day d
JOIN interval i ON  d.id = i.day_id
GROUP_BY d.day
```

Comment: Wait. What does the `int id` and `int day_id` mean? By the way, this program is a class schedule.

Comment: They are two int fields, the int id on the day table is the int auto_increment primary key of the table.